# Select between two dates in sql oracle with hourly counts?

Tags: sql, oracle

i cant find in the forum how i can select from sql counts between two dates, but hourly. I have to extract from server three diferent columns, with date, hour , and count. Finally, the database will look like:

```
    date     hour  count
  29/08/2010,"06","84"
  29/08/2010,"07","95"
  29/08/2010,"08","125"
  29/08/2010,"09","133"
  29/08/2010,"10","99"
  29/08/2010,"11","105"
  29/08/2010,"12","109"
  29/08/2010,"13","135"
  29/08/2010,"14","160"
  29/08/2010,"15","119"
  29/08/2010,"16","127"
  29/08/2010,"17","126"
  29/08/2010,"18","147"
  29/08/2010,"19","125"
  29/08/2010,"20","135"
  29/08/2010,"21","108"
  29/08/2010,"22","12"
  30/08/2010,"04","3"
  30/08/2010,"05","92"
  30/08/2010,"06","438"
  30/08/2010,"07","471"
  30/08/2010,"08","329"
  30/08/2010,"09","212"
    .  ..  . ..  . .
   ..  . . . .  . . .
```

If we are talking about the date, the variable name is TRXDATE. I know is something like this:

```
          TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRXDATE,'DD/MM,"TO_CHAR(TRXDATE,'HH24')","COUNT(*)"
```

And between two dates is exactly like this:

```
  select * from sgco.cardusage where trxdate between TO_DATE('20/01/2014','dd/mm/yyyy') and TO_DATE('21/01/2014','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

But how i can join these two commands two get hourly daily counts between two dates???

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your question?  Can you provide sample results?

Comment: Select [Expression for Hour], count(*)  From TABLE group by [Expression for Hour]

Comment: I need the command to get it Gordon Linoff. And the sample is up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get it via `group by`:

```
select TO_CHAR(trunc(trxdate), 'dd/mm/yyyy') day,
       TO_CHAR(trunc(trxdate, 'hh'), 'hh24') hour,
       count(*) nb
from sgco.cardusage
where trxdate between TO_DATE('20/01/2014','dd/mm/yyyy')
                  and TO_DATE('22/01/2014','dd/mm/yyyy')
group by trunc(trxdate), trunc(trxdate, 'hh')
```

Comment: And where i can include the dates?? if i need between 20/01/2014 and 21/01/2014????

Comment: Ah ok, I did not get that! See my comment!

Comment: Why? What do you get?

Comment: Im working in R. But when i need to get into a server, i need a Sql Oracle command. That command says error.

Comment: When i nedd to days i say "select * from sgco.cardusage where trxdate between TO_DATE('20/01/2014','dd/mm/yyyy') and TO_DATE('21/01/2014','dd/mm/yyyy')"

Comment: [1] "HY000 923 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected\n"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       [2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select

Comment: Ok, I got it, `date` is a reserved keyword. Corrected.

Comment: Ok my friend, it works as well. But it only shows one date,  20/01/2014. I need it between two dates. Please help me to fix it for two dates so i can give you the Like. Thx!

Comment: Check my last attempt - `TO_DATE('22/01/2014','dd/mm/yyyy')` is the good solution since it's midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below ?

```
SQL> with t (date#, value#) as (
  2   select sysdate+rownum/(24*5), mod(abs(round(dbms_random.value(1,100),0)),9)
  3   from dual connect by level <= 100
  4  )
  5  select trunc(trunc(date#,'HH24'),'DD') trxdate, to_char(trunc(date#,'HH24'),'HH24') hour#, count(*) trxdate from t
  6  group by trunc(date#,'HH24')
  7  order by 1,2
  8  /

TRXDATE  HO    TRXDATE                                                          
-------- -- ----------                                                          
17.03.14 18          3                                                          
17.03.14 19          5                                                          
17.03.14 20          5                                                          
17.03.14 21          5                                                          
17.03.14 22          5                                                          
17.03.14 23          5                                                          
18.03.14 00          5                                                          
18.03.14 01          5                                                          
18.03.14 02          5                                                          
18.03.14 03          5                                                          
18.03.14 04          5                                                          
18.03.14 05          5                                                          
18.03.14 06          5                                                          
18.03.14 07          5                                                          
18.03.14 08          5                                                          
18.03.14 09          5                                                          
18.03.14 10          5                                                          
18.03.14 11          5                                                          
18.03.14 12          5                                                          
18.03.14 13          5                                                          
18.03.14 14          2
```

Comment: Hey Man where i can add the dates? i need these dates: between 20/01/2014 and 21/01/2014. thx

Comment: WHERE clause between FROM and GROUP BY should work to you: "FROM t WHERE date# between .... GROUP BY"